# How to control HightChart Pie Chart/Donut Chart label font-weight in config

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization, pie-chart, donut-chart

All:

I am pretty new to High Chart, for their PieChart/DonutChart, I wonder which config param control the font-weight of each slice label text?

For this example below, when there are so many labels, the bold font seems not quite good, I just want to use normal font

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the fontWeight param in the style object.

```
dataLabels: {
            style:{
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            }
        }
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/n09L3jjL/

Comment: @SebastianBochan  Thanks, I will use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the boldface from the labels by adding `<span style="font-weight: normal;">` to the `formatter` function in `dataLabels` for the "Versions" series:

```
dataLabels: {
    formatter: function () {
    // display only if larger than 1
        return this.y > 1 ? '<span style="font-weight: normal;">' + 
            this.point.name + ': ' + this.y + '%</span>' : null;
    }
}
```

Note that the `</span>` goes at the end of what you're returning from this function.

The resulting chart looks like this:

[image]

Here's an updated version of the demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/4tfu584x/

I hope this is helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful